# Why google colab is showing missing module/package even when everything is installed?

Tags: python, pandas, database, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am trying to target search an enzyme from chembl database. For doing that I have written this command line in google colab.

```
! pip install chembl_webresource_client
```

It showed that the new version of flask and other packages are not updated. So I manually updated all the packages.

```
import pandas as pd
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client

# Target search for enzyme
target = new_client.target
target_query = target.search('estrone sulfatase')
targets = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(target_query)
targetsenter code here
```

Even then when I am trying to target search it's repeatedly showing me this error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_encode' from 'requests_cache.cache_keys' 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests_cache/cache_keys.py)
```

I have tried to write the code in Jupyter Notebook. But it's showing the same error there also.

Comment: `!pip install requests-cache==0.6.0` should fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. May I know how you have found out which version to install? Previously I installed requests-cache version 0.7.0 which didn't work apparently.

Comment: I looked at the requirements of chembl_webresource_client and I saw `requests-cache>=0.6.0`, so I gave it a try.